# How to Filter a Column of a Data Frame Based on an List?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

For example I have a data frame like `df1` and I splitted it into 5 parts as in `z`

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("A","C","B","D","E","F","G","H","L","K","P","T") ,y = runif(12))
df1

p <- 5
n <- nrow(df1)
z <- split(df1, cummax(as.numeric(gl(p, n%/%p, n))))
```

And I have other data frame `df2` :

```
df2 <- data.frame(
    emp_name = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
    salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25))
```

Now I want to filter `df2$emp_name` based on `x` values in `z`. For example, I want to filter `df2$emp_name` based on x values in `z[["1"]]`

If `z` was a data frame I know that I can use `filter <- subset(df2, emp_name %in% z$x)` but I don't know how to do it where `z` is a list instead of a data frame.

Thanks and appreciating your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, here is an answer but not cool

```
library(dplyr)

for(vi in 1:length(z)){
  print(subset(df2, df2$emp_name %in% z[[vi]]$x))
}
```

If you want to get every result, make a null list